# How to have same insertion order in RestTemplate Multipart upload having same key

Tags: spring-boot, multipartform-data, resttemplate

I have an API where i have **document and description** as formdata key like this-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yv2RA.png

How to have same Insertion order for the doc upload.
The formdata keys are losing its order in an array.

**Wanted document and description to be sent in same order in which it is added.**
How to maintain the same order.

My code -

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> valueMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();

for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
   Resource fileResource = new FileSystemResource(htmlFile);
   String descriptionJson = "{ "a" : "a"};
   valueMap.add("document" ,fileResource);
   valueMap.add("description" , descriptionJson);
}

HttpEntity<?> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(valueMap, httpHeaders);
Object postResponse = restTemplate.exchange(url, httpMethod, httpEntity, String.class);
```

Comment: But `LinkedMultiValueMap` has order though? so it is really sent out of order? in the document said it wraps LinkedHashMap and LinkedList.

Comment: Yes the order is getting changed  while sent.